# How to restrict access the app through the subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I'm binding the app with domain first time and I have bound my app with the domain and it has an `A Name`.

```
www.domain.de
```

I have also two subdomains.

```
api.domain.de
admin.domain.de
```

Now I have one static app and it must be accessed through only the main domain, not by subdomains.

**What I Tried**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ={api.domain.de}[NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^({folderName})
RewriteRule ^$ http://{domain}.de//?%1 [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone help to achieve this?

Comment: If possible those should be separate http hosts, that way you can keep the configuration separate. If that is not possible, for example because you are using a cheap hosting provider, then you need to implement some simple rewriting rules that take the requests http host into consideration. You will find lots of examples for that here on SO. Start at the right hand side unter "Related"...

Comment: Yes I'm trying to write some code in `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Sure, I understand. And that is why I mentioned the existing examples. I added a general answer though to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably is a straight forward approach...

It implements an external redirection of *all* requests to any hostname that differs from "www.example.com" while keeping the requested path and query string.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301]
```

I would, however, expect that there *are* certain requests you do *not* want to redirect. Both hostnames you mentioned in your question indicate that they are meant to be used for specific purposes. So most likely those requests should *not* get redirected?

This can be implemented using an additional internal rewriting that takes care of such requests *before* the more general redirection gets applied:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /admin/$1 [END]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [QSA,R=301]
```

These are just examples obviously, you will need to adapt them to fit your specific needs. Your question is vague here, so that is the best we can offer...

**Update**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api.domain.de$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin.domain.de$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://domain.de/projectName/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This works for me... :)

Comment: @SachinShah Thanks for the Update, thanks for sharing your final solution. A few comments: 1. the regular expressions in the RewriteCond's should use `\.` instead of just `.`. Both works here, but only "by accident. You want to learn about regular expressions to understand this. 2. the pattern in the RewriteRule should be `^(.*)$`, better even `^/?(.*)$` instead of just `(.*)$`. 3. The `L` flag does not make any sense with an `R` flag, you can omit it. Yes, I know it is often shown, still it makes no sense. 4. Please use the name "example.com" instead of your example host name. Thanks!